# Webpack иногда не подхватывает измненения и не перестраивает main.js main.css

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, scss, alpine-linux

Иногда **WebPack не подхватывает мои изменения в JSX и SCSS файлах**, и, таким образом, он не компилирует обновленный **main.scss** и **main.js** (иногда).

В моем случае WebPack работает внутри Docker контейнера, установленного в  docker image Linux alpine легковесной версии линукс.

Я хочу через SSH зайти в Docker контейнер и принудительно перекомпилировать изменения с помощью инструмента командной строки WebPack  напрямую.

Может быть есть какой-то ручной способ, как например как-нибудь так:

```
$ WebPack --force-complie или --force-watch --force-rebuild
```

или что-то подобное, чтобы вручную запустить процесс сборки **main.scss** и **main.js**

есть ли способ сделать это?

вот мой файл **webpack.config.js**:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    require("dotenv").config();
}

module.exports = {
    entry: "./assets/shared/main.jsx",
    output: {
        path: "public",
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "eslint-loader"
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader?sourceMap!postcss-loader!sass-loader"
                )
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                // inline base64 URLs for <=4k images, direct URLs for the rest
                loader: "url-loader?limit=4096"
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    stats: { children: false },
    postcss: function () {
        return [autoprefixer];
    },
    eslint: {
        quiet: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
            "NODE_ENV", // This is used to run React in "production" mode
            "API_URL"
        ])
    ]
};
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить в конфиг `watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeoit: 300
    }` например. В некоторых случаях могут быть задержки из - за IDE

Comment: спасибо!!   Я попробую эту опцию!

Comment: @musichen оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ